# plotting pie chart from csv data?

Tags: python, pandas, pie-chart

For data of car performance such as:

```
 Model  Running  Rest  
 1      10       14   
 1      11       13  
 1      12       12  
 2       9       15  
 2      10       14
```

how to plot `Running` and `Rest` each value plot here and also case like for 1st three rows since `Model` no is same?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

df = pd.read_csv('performance.csv')

df.pie(x='Running', y='Rest', autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=140))
```

After seeing few answers on stackoverflow I proceeded as:

```
import csv as csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

colors = ['r', 'g']

with open('performance.csv') as csvfile:
readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

i = 0

for row in readCSV:
    if i == 0:
        activities = [row[1], row[2]]
        title = row[0]
    else:
        slices = [row[1], row[2]]
        plt.title("Model: " + row[0])  
        plt.pie(slices, labels=activities, colors=colors, startangle=90, autopct='%.1f%%')
        plt.show()

    i += 1
```

This code gives me each rows value of `Running` and `Rest` as a pie chart.

But how to get pie chart for say 1st three rows where `Model` column value is same?

Comment: Does it even makes sense to draw a pie chart with two variable? If you want to see the correlation between the two variables why are you not using a scatter plot instead?

Comment: requirement is for the pie chart to understand percentage of Running and Rest values. @cdaiga

Comment: Ok, I now see @suryaRahul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your original `df` you can do something like:

```
In []:
df[['Running', 'Rest']].groupby(df.Model).plot.pie(subplots=True, autopct='%.1f%%')

Out[]:
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello @AChampion can a row wise visualization between `Running`and `Rest` can be done for each row in pandas ?